# Jasmine testing with external javascript

Tags: javascript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Well I am trying to fire up my first Jasmine test with Karma. I want to test my main javascript file declared functions, but I'm stuck on it... In my specRunner.html I included every files which needed, in karma.conf.js I added both my test specification and main js files also `files: ['src/scripts/main.js','src/tests/mySpec.js']`.
In my main.js there is the function I want to use

```
function testFunctionOne(a, b) {
  return a * b;
}
```

So in mySpec.js file there is the test:

```
describe('testFunctionOne function', function () {
  it('should return a * b', function () {
    expect(testFunctionOne(2,4).toEqual(8));
  });
});
```

My question is what am I forgot? What am I making wrong? Keep in mind, this is my first attempt for Jasmine testing.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

`expect(testFunctionOne(2,4)).toEqual(8);` not `expect(testFunctionOne(2,4).toEqual(8));`  I think

Comment: Thank you Alex, I missed this mistyping, but the problem still exist. the erro message now is: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: testFunctionOne

Comment: Can you type `find .` in your project root and send the output?  It could be a path problem.

Comment: If you have the wrong path for the main.js I don't think it'll tell you